# How to send an Ajax request without being redirected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I am trying to send an AJAX request via GET. It works well but I am redirecting to the page. I would like to stay on the same page.

I tried `e.preventDefault()` but it does not work.

```php
// index.php 
<a href="hola.php?id=3" id="link">Signaler</a>
<p id="messageSpam"></p>
```

```
// ajax.js 
$(document).ready(function () {
    let bouton = $('#link');
    $(bouton).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get('hola.php', {id: id}, function(data) {
            $('#messageSpam').text(data);
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: remove `href` value from anchor tag `<a>` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Index.php

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link">Signaler</a>
<p id="messageSpam"></p>
```

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let bouton = $('#link');
    let id = 3;//assume
    $(bouton).on('click', function (e) {
        $.get('hola.php', {id: id}, function(data) {
            $('#messageSpam').text(data);
        });
    });
});
```